# Is it possible to determine with NDB if model is persistent in the datastore or not?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am in process of  migration from `db.Model` to `ndb.Model`. The only issue that I have to solve before finish this migration is that there is no `Model.is_saved` method. I have used `db.Model.is_saved` in my application to determine if sharded counters must be updated on `put`/`delete`, to check for conflicted keys on creating entities etc.

The documentation says that `ndb.Model` has no equivalent for `is_saved` method.  I can reimplement some use cases with `get_or_insert` instead of `is_saved`. But not all of them.

As a dirty hack I can set flag like `_in_memory_instance` for every instance I have created by calling constructor. But it does not solve my issue. I still have to update this flag at least after every `put()` call.

The question is: is there better way to determine if model is persistent in the datastore or not without extra datastore hit?

Edit 1: Forgot to mention: all the entities got keys so check for `Model._has_complete_key()` does not work for me.

Edit 2: After this discussion https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/Tm8NDWIvc70/discussion it seems to be the only way to solve my issue is to use `_post_get_hook`/`_post_put_hook`. I wondering why such a trivial thing was not included in official API.

Edit 3: I ended up with next base class for all my models. Now I can leave my codebase (almost) untouched:

```
class BaseModel(ndb.Model):

    @classmethod
    def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
        self = future.get_result()
        if self:
            self._is_saved = bool(key)

    def _post_put_hook(self, future):
        self._is_saved = future.state == future.FINISHING

    def is_saved(self):
        if self._has_complete_key():
            return getattr(self, "_is_saved", False)
        return False
```

Comment: can you check if the object actually has a key/id? (possibly in a try/except clause). Not familiar with NDB model class, but I recall that db.Model raises an error (or returns None?) if you try to get the id/key of a model instance before it is saved (or possibly it returns `None`). Don't think that would end up with a Datastore hit either. If that works, you could just write a property that's something like `def is_saved(self): return self.key() is None` (or do it with a try/except clause that returns True if an exception is raised and False otherwise).

Comment: Checking the key won't work if your creating a key.  One possible alternative (but may be insufficient) is have a creation_date flag (set to auto_now_add=True). From the docs  "The automatic value is not generated until the entity is written; that is, these options don't provide dynamic defaults."  However if the write fails that value will be set.  Though you should know that the write failed ;-)

Comment: alternately use a _post_put_hook to set your flag indicating it was saved.

Comment: @TimHoffman, but if the OP *isn't* explicitly creating the key then it would work ;P

Comment: Correct, thats why I said "work if your creating a key". I thought I would provide an alternative if they are creating a key ;-)

Comment: Actually not entirely correct, if they provide a parent in the contructor ie newobj=MyModel(parent=otherobj) then a key will be created even though they are not providing a key name or key on object creation. The key exists but is incomplete. The last part of the path will be None

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the same kind of state in NDB you would need a combination of
post-get-hook and post-put-hook to set a flag. Here's a working
example:

```
class Employee(ndb.Model):
  <properties here>

  saved = False  # class variable provides default value

  @classmethod
  def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
    obj = future.get_result()
    if obj is not None:
      # test needed because post_get_hook is called even if get() fails!
      obj.saved = True

  def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    self.saved = True
```

There's no need to check for the status of the future -- when either
hook is called, the future always has a result. This is because the
hook is actually a callback on the future. However there is a need to
check if its result is None!

PS: Inside a transaction, the hooks get called as soon as the put() call returns; success or failure of the transaction doesn't enter affect them.  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/contextclass#Context_call_on_commit for a way to run a hook after a successful commit.

Comment: As discussed [here](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=211) this won't work for entities retrieved trough queries/gql because _post_get_hook isn't called on them and there is no equivalent callback (yet) for queries.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Tim Hoffmans idea you can you a post hook like so:

```
class Article(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()

    is_saved = False

    def _post_put_hook(self, f):
        if f.state == f.FINISHING:
            self.is_saved = True
        else:
            self.is_saved = False


article = Article()
print article.is_saved ## False
article.put()
print article.is_saved ## True
```

I can't guarantee that it's persisted in the datastore. Didn't find anything about it on google :)

On a side not, looking to see if a ndb.Model instance has a key won't probably work since a new instance seems to get a Key before it's ever sent to the datastore. You can look at the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py#2570) to see what happens when you create an instance of the ndb.Model class.

Comment: It is close enough to use it as a workaround. So I vote +1. I'll accept your answer in couple of days if better solution will not appear.

Comment: The only downside I see with this approach as it currently stands is if an entity has been retrieved rather than created then `is_saved` will be `False`.  Which doesn't map to the `db.Model` behaviour of `is_saved()`. To be complete you probably want to add a `_post_get_hook` method that also sets is_saved to True.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mention a key while creating an instance of the Model, you can use the following implementation of `is_saved()` to know if the object has been written to the datastore or not atleast once. (should be appropriate if you are migrating from google.appengine.ext.db to google.appengine.ext.ndb)

Using the example given by @fredrik,

```
class Article(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    
    def is_saved(self):
        if self.key:
            return True
        return False
```

P.S. - I do not know if this would work with google.cloud.ndb