# NDB caching temporary / helper properties. Can I turn it off?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

It looks like temporary variables are also cached when using NDB.

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self._temporary = []
        ndb.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
```

Is there a way not to store the temporary / helper variables in the cache?

EDIT:

Here is a simple test case proving my problem:

```
#Python imports
import unittest

# GAE imports
from google.appengine.ext import testbed
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util
from google.appengine.ext import ndb


class TestModel(ndb.Model):

    username = ndb.StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        self._temp = []
        ndb.Model.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)

class TestModels(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()

        self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub()
        self.testbed.init_urlfetch_stub()
        self.testbed.init_mail_stub()
        self.testbed.init_images_stub()
        self.testbed.init_blobstore_stub()

        self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1)
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=self.policy)

        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()
        self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='ndb-test')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.testbed.deactivate()

    def test1(self):

        test_model = TestModel()
        test_model.username = 'Tom'
        test_model._temp = 'Temporary'
        test_model.put()

        test = TestModel.query().fetch(10)

        self.assertEqual(1, len(test))

        test = test[0]

        self.assertEqual('Tom', test.username)
        self.assertEqual([], test._temp)
```

The last line of the test **self.assertEqual([], test._temp)** fails even though I would expect it to pass.

Is there a way to either not store temporary / helper model properties or have a cleaver way of resetting them every time model is loaded from cache?

Comment: Are you 100% sure, that they are cached? Ndb caches only entities by key (Key.get()) and it should not cache any "helper" variables (that begin with underscore). If I run your code, create new entity, fill the _temporary list and put it, ndb does not store any of those values. Could you describe how did you test it and how did you get to your result, that they are cached?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NDB has a couple of caches - instance memory and memcache. In instance memory, the actual entity itself is cached, so the same entity object will be returned for multiple get calls within the same request.

As long as you're using NDB with caching enabled, this is something you'll have to deal with - for instance, by not storing 'temporary' data on an entity in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for responding. The GAE documentation says: "The names of the attributes are used as the names of the corresponding properties on an entity. Model instance attributes whose names begin with an underscore (_) are ignored, so your application can use such attributes to store data on a model instance that isn't saved to the Datastore." So I think they should also be ignored when using context cache but this is not the case. I'm looking for a solution to make "clear" them when the entity is retrieved form context cache.

Comment: NDB caching isn't storing stuff to the datastore - it's caching stuff in memory. Since it's the very same instance, there's no way for it to reach in and clear things without knowing details about your model. Whatever you are storing here should almost certainly not be associated with the model in the first place.

Comment: "NDB caching isn't storing stuff to the datastore - it's caching stuff in memory." - I'm aware of that. Partial answer to my question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727233/ndb-query-fetch-and-contextoptions and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083254/is-it-possible-to-determine-with-ndb-if-model-is-persistent-in-the-datastore-or

Comment: My point is that that section of the documentation is irrelevant - it refers to how entities are stored in the datastore, not how NDB caches them. Further, NDB explains in the docs how it caches. Disabling the cache is a bit of an extreme reaction to this, and will impact performance - you'd be better off moving these 'temporary' properties off the model, or clearing them yourself. What's the nature of these properties?

Comment: I have added some temporary / helper properties to the model and few property setters so i can track what properties have changed and then use this information to update some sharded counters that hold statistics about the data i have in the datastore. The solution was as you pointed not to save this data in the model. Thanks!