# Setting is_saved property of NDB model object isn't working as expected

Tags: app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

I have never seen this before, google didn't seem to offer up much help here, apologies if the title is vague, wasn't sure what to call this problem.

I'm migrating from ext.db to ndb, and some of the logic in my models use ext.db's `is_saved()` function. The [migration doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb#entities) sends me over to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083254/is-it-possible-to-determine-with-ndb-if-model-is-persistent-in-the-datastore-or/12096066#12096066), which tells me I can set a default property like `is_saved` to `False`, set some post/get hooks that change it to `True` and I'll get the same functionality.

So, I have a Workout model:

```
class Workout(ndb.Expando):
  ..properties..

  is_saved = False

  def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwds):

    self._summary = None
    self._description = None
    self._snapshots = kwds.get('_snapshots')
    self._action = kwds.get('_action')
    self._record_id = kwds.get('_record_id')
    self._packageNumber = None
    super(Workout, self).__init__(parent=None, **kwds)

  @classmethod
  def _post_get_hook(cls, key, future):
    obj = future.get_result()
    if obj is not None:
      # test needed because post_get_hook is called even if get() fails!
      obj.is_saved = True

  def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    logging.info(future)
    self.is_saved = True
```

Other logic through my codebase ends up saving (or `put()`ing) the entity, and I eventually save a `workout` variable of the entity:

```
>>> workout
Workout(key=Key('Workout', 5132107961597952), calories=2.0, creation_date=datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 24, 18, 23, 0, 769000), distance=1.0,  elapsedSeconds=21600, is_deleted=False, is_saved=True)
```

Great, `is_saved` is `True`, logic works. Accessing it though,

```
>>> workout.is_saved
False
```

Ok, what if I set it myself:

```
>>> workout.is_saved = True
>>> workout.is_saved
False
```

Well, this defies all logic and reason. Maybe it's the object?

```
>>> workout.calories = 0.555
>>> workout.calories
0.555
```

Ok so, not a problem with the object. I have no idea what's wrong here.